# How to view everything in the terminal without having to press down

Tags: terminal

On my old machine, if I run a command with a large amount of output, it outputs it all, and I have to scroll up to see the first lines. I liked this.

On this machine, it only displays as many lines as will fit on the screen, ending with `:` and I need to press down (or pageDown) to scroll down, and 'q' to quit. I do not like this, it is very annoying.

How do I disable this? I don't even know how to ask this question, I think this is 'less' but I have not chosen to use 'less', it seems to be a default which is hidden somewhere.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: Terminator in Ubuntu, also Terminal in Ubuntu, and Iterm2 in Mac. They're all doing it =(

Comment: Gah, its `git` -_- it has a pager setting

Comment: As you've figured out, this isn't a generic teminal issue, but is specific to the application you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is `git` which you are using, it might be git itself ['paging' things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183920/849697):

For single commands, `git --no-pager diff` instead of `git diff`

For all commands always, configure git to not use paging: `git config --global core.pager cat`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.